# resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false Doesn't Work in CurvedNavigationBar Flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard, navigationbar

I struggle with flutter CurvedNavigationBar.
Every time keyboard appears, CurvedNavigationBar sticks on Top of the keyboard.
I found many & different answers for this issue, but nothing worked for me.
I added resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false inside my Scafold, with no luck.

Any suggestions, please?

Thanks in advance!

```html
**This is a part of my code 

      var pagesAll = [
    SignUpScreen(),
    HomeScreen(),
    OtherScreen()
  ];
  GlobalKey<CurvedNavigationBarState> _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          key: _bottomNavigationKey,
          index: _page,
          height: 60.0,
          items: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.perm_identity, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.home, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.message, size: 30),
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _page = index;
            });
          },
          letIndexChange: (index) => true,
        ),
        body: pagesAll[_page]);
  }

/*    Also the Sign up Sceen  */

 Widget initWidget() {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(90)),
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 162, 118).withOpacity(.75),
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 162, 118).withOpacity(.75),
                    Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 162, 118).withOpacity(.75),
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 70),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              height: 54,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      offset: Offset(0, 10),
                      blurRadius: 50,
                      color: Color(0xffEEEEEE)),
                ],
              ),
              child: TextField(
                controller: fullName,
                cursorColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 162, 118).withOpacity(.75),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 162, 118).withOpacity(.75),
                  ),
                  hintText: "Full Name",
                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              height: 54,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      offset: Offset(0, 10),
                      blurRadius: 50,
                      color: Color(0xffEEEEEE)),
                ],
              ),
              child: TextField(
                controller: email,
                cursorColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 162, 118).withOpacity(.75),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.email,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 162, 118).withOpacity(.75),
                  ),
                  hintText: "Email",
                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),) }
```

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that you;ve tried so far

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yeah sure! I updated the post with some code

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't stick to mine. maybe there are some other reasons somewhere that are affecting your bottom navigation. and as additional advice, I think its a good practice to show fullscreen when dealing with forms or text fields because you don't want your user to toggle to another page while filling out forms, especially signup forms.

Comment: @john I didn't expect that.   I'm going to test it on more devices.
Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, thanks to @john, I realised that I didn't include resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false in a parent wigdet Scafold.